# Running TFS 2012 Coded UI test in the context of a workgroup test machine

Tags: security, deployment, tfs, coded-ui-tests

We're having an issue in our lab environment running coded UI tests.

Note that the deployment completes successfully but the test fails with the following error:

> **Deployment**
>
> Lab environment: Win 7 VM
>
> Build definition did not specify
> a clean snapshot. It is a best practice to use clean snapshot when
> running the lab workflow.
>
> The application was deployed successfully from the following build location:\tfssvr106\TFS\BuildDrop\ServerAssistant_Production\ServerAssistant_Production_20130816.1
>
> Build definition did not specify a post deployment snapshot. It is a
> best practice to take post deployment snapshot when running the lab
> workflow.
>
> **Test Results**
>
> Test run (Id) : ServerAssistant - Coded
> UI_20130816.12 (96) Test run needs investigation Test run details
>
> 0 of 1 test(s) passed, 1 failed, 0 inconclusive, View Test Results

The test results have the following error…

> The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required.

The Diagnostic logging from the build has the following…

> TestDirectory = \tfssvr106\TFS\BuildDrop\ServerAssistant_Production\ServerAssistant_Production_20130816.1

We don’t want the tests running from the build drop location because that is a domain server share and the test VM is a workgroup machine. We'd prefer the agent on the workgroup VM to run the tests from its local C:

If we authenticate the workgroup machine to the build drop share using my domain account, the tests run fine.

All the files are present and ready to run from C: via my deploy task.  How do we get the tests to run from C: of the VM?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to run your test controllers and test agents on machines that are in a work group and not in a domain, or machines that run in different domains that do not have a two-way trust relationship, you must follow these steps as part of your installation process:

On each computer where you will install a test controller or a test agent, create a local user account that is a member of the Administrators group. Use the same account and password on each machine.

Use this user account for your test controllers when you install and configure them.

Add this account to the TeamTestAgentService group on the test controller machine.

Caution
When you add this user account to the group, do not include the name of the local machine. For example, do not add the user account as \. Just add  as the user account for the group.

Install and configure your test agents using this same account.

Note
During installation, simple file sharing is automatically turned off for users who connect to a controller from a Windows XP Professional computer in a Work Group. To verify this, open Windows Explorer, choose Tools, choose Folder Options, choose Next, choose the View tab, and then choose Use Simple File Sharing (Recommended).

Full information can be referenced from this link:
[Requirements for Workgroups and Multiple Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh546459.aspx#workgroup)

Comment: Thanks very much!  We ended up being able to reconfigure our servers to run in a single-domain configuration, but this will be helpful to know for the future!